# Ninject 2: Is there an equivalent to 1.5's InjectPropertiesWhere?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-2

I am using Ninject 1.5 in my MVC project. It works nicely, but since we have Ninject 2, I could upgrade (and additionaly use per request behavior, which didn't work properly in 1.5). Ninject 1.5 had `InjectPropertiesWhere` function, which is missing in Ninject 2 (at least it was when I tested it some time ago). Is there something similar?

Example of `InjectPropertiesWhere`:

```
return Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>()
    .InjectPropertiesWhere(p => p.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
    .InjectPropertiesWhere(p => p.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .InjectPropertiesWhere(p => p.Name == "ApplicationCache")
    .InjectPropertiesWhere(p => p.Name == "CurrentPrincipal")
    .InjectPropertiesWhere(p => p.Name == "CTEmailSender")
    .InjectPropertiesWhere(p => p.Name == "CTSettings");
```

Comment: Looked in the test suite? This is pretty involved stuff so I'd expect there to be a succinct set of tests that'd double as lovely samples!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not supported this way by Ninject 2. You have 4 Options:

1. Switch to Constructor injection, which is always the prefered way of injection.
2. Add the Inject Attribute to your properties (Or another attribute and configure it as the inject attribute)
3. Use `WithProperty("propertyName", ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<MyType>())`
4. The behavior can be added by writing an activation strategy that injects the configured properties. The configuration which properties shall be injected can be added to the bindings metadata using an extension method.

Comment: +1 great answer as usual; Top tip: highlighting stuff and pressing Ctrl-K puts backticks around things which highlights code artifacts. This is critical for angle bracks, which otherwise get swallowed by the markdown-ish stuff around here. (Hover over the buttons above the editing region for all the shortcuts)

Comment: I moved to constructors everything I could, but since there are some cilcular dependencies, not all could be made. I don't like adding `Inject` attribute, because it adds additional dependency. Constructor injection is painful, because all inheriting classes have to contain all parameters in their constructors. Anyway, I switched to Ninject 2 and got PerRequest behavior out of the box and better MVC support, which is nice. Thanks for help.

Comment: @LukeLed: remember that batches of dependencies that travel around in herds are often [Aggregate services](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.ploeh.dk%2F2010%2F02%2F02%2FRefactoringToAggregateServices.aspx&ei=RPFaTbmzMMLAhAeFmqGRDQ&usg=AFQjCNHlOqvEPlV98J8DuU_KG72A9QHdKw&sig2=QEFqaoGWTaV9jUFrOqcB8Q) or missing abstractions in disguise though.